# d3 selectall on click is not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

In the following code I am drawing a line chart and added filter 
to draw circles for only certain coordinates depending on the condition.

What I want to do is if user clicks on those circles they should be able to see alert message with data coordinates.

I added onclick function but it’s not getting called.

```js
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.2.2/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.0.0-beta/nv.d3.js"></script>

<script>
var width = 900, height = 500;

nv.addGraph(function () {
    var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
        .width(width)
        .height(height)
        .margin({
        left: 75,
        right: 50
    });
    chart.xAxis.axisLabel('Time (ms)')
        .tickFormat(d3.format(',r'));
    chart.yAxis.axisLabel('Voltate (vt)')
        .tickFormat(d3.format('.2f'));
    
    var sampleSVG =d3.select('#chart svg');
    
    sampleSVG
    .datum(myData())
    .transition().attr('width', width).attr('height', height).duration(500)
  .call(chart)
   .each("end", function() {
    var data = myData();
           
     d3.select('.nv-groups').selectAll("circle")
    .data(data[0].values.filter(function(d) { return d.y > 3000; }))
    .enter().append("circle")
    .style("stroke", "gray")
    .style("fill", "blue")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return chart.xAxis.scale()(d.x);})
                .attr("cy", function(d) { return chart.yAxis.scale()(d.y);})
    //.on("click", function(d) { alert('on click called.'+chart.lines.x() );   } );  
    
   });  


},function(){
 var svg_circles = d3.selectAll("circle");
 //alert('in function'+svg_circles);
 svg_circles.on('click',
  function(){
   alert('on clk called ');
   console.log("test");
 });
});




function myData() {
    return data = [{
        "values": [{
            "x": 0,
            "y": 3235,
   "isAlert" :'1',
   "alertInfo" : 'Alert generated for this trade'
   
        }, {
            "x": 173,
            "y": 2114
        }, {
            "x": 347,
            "y": 1724
        }, {
            "x": 526,
            "y": 2703
        }, {
            "x": 700,
            "y": 2980
        }, {
            "x": 931,
            "y": 3086
        }, {
            "x": 1058,
            "y": 2881
        }, {
            "x": 1220,
            "y": 2817
        }, {
            "x": 1399,
            "y": 2242
        }, {
            "x": 1584,
            "y": 2639
        }, {
            "x": 1752,
            "y": 3122
        }, {
            "x": 1983,
            "y": 3157
        }, {
            "x": 2105,
            "y": 3391
        }, {
            "x": 2284,
            "y": 3441
        }, {
            "x": 2469,
            "y": 3356
        }, {
            "x": 2637,
            "y": 3498
        }, {
            "x": 2811,
            "y": 3753
        }, {
            "x": 3042,
            "y": 3384
        }, {
            "x": 3169,
            "y": 3399
        }, {
            "x": 3331,
            "y": 3399
        }, {
            "x": 3522,
            "y": 2164
        }, {
            "x": 3690,
            "y": 2129
        }, {
            "x": 3863,
            "y": 2200
        }, {
            "x": 4095,
            "y": 2292
        }],
        "key": "Stocks Data",
        "color": null
    }]}
</script>
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.0.0-beta/nv.d3.css">
```

```html
<div id="chart">
    <svg></svg>     
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that your circles are not at the front of the SVG. One quick workaround is to append your circles to NVD3's interactive layer in your `each()` function and remove the callback from `addGraph()`.

```
var svg = d3.select(this);
svg.select('.nv-interactive').selectAll("circle")
```

However, this partially blocks the mouseover/tooltip events to NVD3's points (under `#nv-point-clips`).

EDIT: Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g6sp5p0f/9/. This is using NVD3's current master release, so it may not work with a newer/development version.

Comment: tried that way , but its not working ,please post any example if you have.